# Delete files by filename to determine date in WinSCP

Tags: delete-file, winscp

We have a vendor who sends us files via a SFTP server. I need to download these to Windows server. I'm using a simple WinSCP script to connect to the server, delete old files and then download the most recent files.

For whatever reason, the vendor keeps sending old files with an updated time stamp. So I use a WinSCP command like:

```
rm *<3D
```

And that deletes files where the timestamp is over 3 days old, but they are sending me files that are over a month old, but with an updated time stamp. Because of this, they are sending hundreds of files as opposed to a handful of files. I need to download these files in six different regions to different servers. The connection is slow and I need to do this hourly. When there are hundreds of files, sometimes the connection times out to display the folder, or I don't finish downloading all the files in time.

I keep asking the vendor to fix things on their end to stop sending me old reports with new timestamps, but months later they have still yet to fix things on their end.

Can I create a Powershell or VBS script to connect, parse the files by the file name to determine a date, compare that to the server date and then use that to delete files before I try to download everything in that folder?

For example, I have a file named "agentScheduleSummary_2_**0527210600**.txt".

The number string at the end is a 10 digit number with two digits in order for each of:

- MM = Month
- DD = Day
- YY = Year
- HH = Hour
- MI = Minute

In a purely Powershell or VBS script I can parse the file name to get a date, but how would I combine this with a WinSCP script to delete files older than 3 days old based on filename, then after that only download the past 3 days of files (and even then preferrably do a synchronize or a "`get * -resume -neweronly`" to only download the absolute latest files I don't already have downloaded locally?

Thanks!

Comment: Because I need to download them to multiple servers for different regions around the globe, I can't delete them after I download them. (The vendor is sending me global files that apply everywhere and then I have to download those to North American servers, European servers, APAC servers, etc.)

The vendor keeps uploading old files after I delete them as well. I've been asking for this to get fixed upstream for months and sadly I'm not getting that support upstream.

This integration impacts paying employees accurately so if it breaks, an employee might not get paid.

Comment: I didn't think "Remember already downloaded files" would work because the timestamps of old files keep getting updated by the vendor, so I assume WinSCP would see them as new/updated files, but I want to try that but I can't see to get that script to work.

I authenticate with a RSA token and a passphrase and I'm not seeing how to integrate those into a session URL properly.

Comment: When writing "timestamp" in the context of your question, please make sure you always mention if you mean the timestamps in file attributes/metadata or the timestamps in the file names. + WinSCP GUI can generate a URL with private key for you. Just check "Advanced settings" on https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#url. Or do not use the URL, but the actual [`SessionOptions`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions) properties, like `SshPrivateKeyPath`.